# Why does the jquery ui slider return an object?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

When I do

```
console.log($('#my_slider').slider('value'))
```

it returns `[object Object]`  Does anyone know why it doesn't return the actual value of the slider like it says it is supposed to in the documentation?

Comment: It does, just not how you're doing it.

Comment: I'll find the answer in a second

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: `console.log($('#my_slider').slider('value')[0])`

Answer (score 2):

You should use ([here doc](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Slider#option-value))

```
console.log($('#my_slider').slider( "option", "value" ))
```

Comment: That still returns [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

This is to allow method chaining.

http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/#.UHqPHMXLSKg

The returned object that you are seeing is the original matched set (#my_slider). So, if you had other jQuery methods to call on this you could add them to the end of your statement.

```
$('#my_slider').slider('value').othermethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for .draggable and should work for .slider too

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
       stop: function (s) {
          console.log(s);
       }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me on the demo page for slider:

```
$('#slider').slider('value');
```

Here: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/hotelrooms.html

Might want to look at your implementation.