# jquery ui slider element returns object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to control the height of bars in a graph with sliders.  This is based off the the slider example found [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker). I'm having issues with getting the values from the sliders.  I've created [a JSfiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/sevenless/cXMkN/).

The problem is in the function refeshGraph()

```
function refreshGraph() {
var jan = $("slider1").slider("option","value"),
feb = $("slider2").slider("option","value"),
mar = $("slider3").slider("option","value"),
apr = $("slider4").slider("option","value"),
may = $("slider5").slider("option","value");

console.log(feb)

sliderData = new Array(
        [jan,'Jan','#222222'],
        [feb,'Feb','#7D252B'],
        [mar,'Mar','#EB9781'],
        [apr,'Apr','#FFD2B5'],
        [may,'May','#4A4147']
    );


$('.exampleSimpleColors').show();
$('#exampleSimple').html('');
$('#exampleSimple').jqbargraph({ data: sliderData});

}
```

Instead of the values being stored in the variables I get the whole slider object.  I'm aware of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881198/why-does-the-jquery-ui-slider-return-an-object), where the OP had the same issue. I've attempted to apply the answers, but have not been successful.

Comment: Honestly not sure if this applies, but the docs mention that the value setter method requires something like `$("slider5").slider("option","value", 15);` which differs from the fiddle...not sure if the way the setting is happening is affecting the getters.

Comment: it looks like your error is with the jqbargrah({data: sliderData}) method.  i believe you see object Object because sliderData is an Array object.  So you are loading the full array in every instance of the jqbargraph invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget **#** in slider declaration

in your code `$("slider1").slider("option","value"),`
but should be `$("#slider1").slider("option","value"),`

Fix that and It will work.